# Wrong Millisecond Separator in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, datetime

I really can't figure out why the instruction `SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), GETDATE(), 114)` outputs, for instance,

```
13:04:31:997
```

instead of

```
13:04:31.997
```

Why is the milliseconds separator a `:` insted of a `.`? In case you need to know, I need to be able to check if a certain time is between two time values stored as XML in a table. The problem is that the separator in this table is, as it is normal for me, a `.`, so that using comparisons between the two formats returns wrong results because one uses `.` and the other uses `:`. Is there any way I can get the time with the `.` separator without using string functions like `REPLACE` or without changing the format stored in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try to keep the format as `datetime` when you do the comparison. In SQL Server 2008 there is a new data type `time` that would have been helpful but in SQL Server 2005 we have to use `datetime` instead.

I guess that you are using `convert(..., 114)` to only get the time part from a `datetime` variable. You can use this code to remove the date part and still have a `datetime` variable.

```
declare @dt datetime
set @dt = '2001-01-01T10:01:02.000'
select dateadd(d, datediff(d, @dt, 0), @dt)
```

Result:

```
1900-01-01 10:01:02.000
```

When you extract data from XML using `.value` you specify the datatype to be used. If you only have the time part in the XML and you specify `datetime` you will get the time of the date '1900-01-01'. So you can do the comparison using `datetime`  like this.

```
declare @T table (ID int, XMLCol xml)

insert into @T
select 1, '<t1>10:01:01.123</t1><t2>10:01:02.123</t2>' union all
select 2, '<t1>11:01:01.123</t1><t2>11:01:02.123</t2>'

declare @dt datetime
set @dt = '2001-01-01T10:01:02.000'

select T.ID
from @T as T
where dateadd(d, datediff(d, @dt, 0), @dt) between 
        T.XMLCol.value('t1[1]', 'datetime') and 
        T.XMLCol.value('t2[1]', 'datetime')
```

Result:

```
ID
1
```

Answer (score 2):

That's exactly what [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) says for style 114:

> hh:mi:ss:mmm(24h)

I don't know of any way of changing the separator used. I would suggest converting the XML-formatted value to a datetime instead of converting the current date into a textual value. After all, you're logically comparing dates and times, not strings.

Comment: You are right, but string ordering gives precisely the same results, and that's why I am using it.

Comment: @SQL: But by converting the other way instead, you don't need to worry about formatting to a string. It's generally a better approach - convert data *towards* the most logical data format rather than away from it.